# System PIP instead of virtualenv PIP by default?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

After using virtualenv with pip off-and-on for a couple of days, I've found that the version of PIP that is used after the virtualenv is actived is the global PIP instead of the PIP relative to that environment; such that if you don't set the shell environment variable `export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true`, pip will install whatever new package (e.g. pip install argparse) to the global scope instead of only to the virtualenv.

I would expect PIP to install to the virtualenv by default, if that virtualenv is activated.

Is there a reasoning behind it *not* working that way by default?

See explanation [here](http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/browse_thread/thread/ac9f4ce591359998/3b7268dea5a88928) for how `PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV` works.

Comment: FWIW: The virtualenvs I use have their own copy of pip which installs in that virtualenv.

Comment: @delnan How do they get their own copy of pip?

Comment: Recent versions (1.4 onward) of virtualenv should install a per env copy of pip automatically. What version of virtualenv are you using?

Answer (score 4):

It is not the first time I see someone reporting the same issue. I don't know what is happening, but some people discourage the use o `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate` because it can mess up your `$PATH`.

There is a way pip will always respect your virtualenv: don't rely on `$PATH`. Use:

```
/path/to/venv/bin/pip install MYPACKAGE
```

It would be nice to find out what is happening to you and share your solution with others. Meanwhile, it may be ok to use the absolute path to pip.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a virtualenv, the `activate` file *hardcodes* the variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` to the location in which you first created the root directory. This variable is then exported when you `source <your-venv>/bin/activate`.

Consequently, if you move the virtualenv directory subsequent to its creation, the hardcoded file path will be incorrect.

Just open `<your-venv>/bin/activate` in a text editor and make sure `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set to the new path of your virtualenv directory:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Full/path/to/<your-venv>"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
```

before running `source <your-venv>/bin/activate` again.

Then of course you can test the version of `pip` with `which pip` which should produce:

```
/Full/path/to/<your-venv>/bin/pip
```

rather than `/usr/bin/pip` or `/bin/pip` etc.